# Overloaded ifstream operator>> can't access class private members

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, ifstream

I'm trying to overload the ifstream operator>>, but I keep getting the error: "******** is private within this context", where ****** is the member variable's name. My program uses a class, Matrix, which has a variable for rows, columns and a 2D array to hold the values. I've successfully overloaded the ostream << operator, but the ifstream is giving me more trouble. Any help is greatly appreciated!

(To clarify, my goal is to read text from a .txt file into my matrix, that is why I am using ifstream and not istream)

Here's my Matrix.h file: (a simplified version, at least)

```
class Matrix;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& potato);
ifstream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& potato);

class Matrix
{
    //constructors etc.

    //streams
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& potato);
    friend ifstream& operator>>(istream& in, Matrix& potato);

    private:
    double ** matrix; // the matrix array
    unsigned rows; // # rows
    unsigned cols; // # columns
};
```

Here is the implementation of the ifstream operator>> from Matrix.cpp:

```
ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& in, Matrix& potato)
{
    double temp;
    string strDouble;
    for (int a = 0; a < potato.rows; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < potato.cols; ++b)
        {
            in >> strDouble;
            temp = stod(strDouble);
            potato.matrix[a][b] = temp;
        }
    }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: `ifstream`, `istream`, note the difference. (and it should be `istream`, every time)

Comment: Will this work for reading text from a file into the matrix?

Comment: Yes. The iostream classes were designed to be used polymorphically. `ifstream` inherits from `istream`, so a parameter of type `istream&` will accept an argument of type `ifstream`.

Comment: Note that, in case it wasn't clear, the actual error I was pointing out was that in your class, you've declared a friend function which takes an argument of type `istream&`, but in your function definition, you are taking an argument of type `ifstream&`. The compiler sees these as two different functions, and the one you actually defined (taking `ifstream&`) was not declared as a friend, so you get an error about accessing private members. You *can* make it compile by making your declaration and your definition both take `ifstream&`, but the standard idiom is to accept and return `istream&`.

Comment: Ah I see, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!